# Shortcut to collapse a paragraph/outline in OneNote?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2010

[This](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/onenote-help/use-outlines-to-structure-notes-and-ideas-HA010214060.aspx#BM4) describes a way to collapse outlines with the mouse. Is this possible to do with keyboard only?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/onenote-help/keyboard-shortcuts-in-onenote-2013-HA102749248.aspx

[image]

It's not possible to change this shortcuts in onenote 2013 (you can change them in word 2013). You can however, use autohotey, to "change" them. I use this ahk script for example:

```
^Down::Send !+{+}
^Up::Send !+-
```

This maps Ctrl+Up and Crtl+Down to collapsing and expanding outlines.

Answer (score 8):

Back in the days, these where <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>_</kbd> (Underscore) to collapse and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>. Because the Ribbon has been added, these now require an additional <kbd>Shift</kbd> press, thus:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>_</kbd> (Underscore) to Collapse
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> to Expand

— **Source:** [Dummies - How to Use Word 2010's Outline View](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-use-word-2010s-outline-view.navId-405498.html) (This would also apply to OneNote)

Comment: Any ideas how to change this shortcut ?

Answer (score 0):

YES!! So OneNote nested lists sometimes breaks, in that the icons do not show up as they are supposed to. This is likely some sort of cache issue within the application. Regardless... The shortcut is a workaround to the missing icon (the plus symbol or more likely the chevron like symbol). Then by navigating to another page in OneNote then back to your list... you will magically see that it is working again!! Yay!
Power user hack.