# How can I expand or collapse bulleted or numbered lists in OneNote?

Tags: microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2013

When I make lists of things in OneNote, sometimes I wish that I could collapse some sections down so that I can view more of the "outline" of what I am writing, as opposed to all text.

For example, I would like to just display the sub headings, and not the items, but retain all the data:

[image: bulleted list in OneNote]

Is there a quick and easy way I can collapse these subheadings down?

Comment: Full answer (with keyboard shortcuts) here: https://superuser.com/questions/400418/shortcut-to-collapse-a-paragraph-outline-in-onenote

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you highlight your mouse cursor over the bullet (a bit to the left of it, actually), OneNote should give you the option to move that item somewhere else (by showing you a 4 pointed arrow). Instead of moving it, just double click and that list will collapse to show just the top level item, and give you a little plus sign to signify that you can expand that item.

In the picture below, you can see that I have collapsed the first two subheadings and my mouse (which is invisible in the screenshot) is hovering over the grey arrow to the left of "a third subheading" where I could double click and it would collapse that section like the previous two.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

if you're using Windows 10, take cursor to 'this is a sub heading' then press the following keyboard combination:

"alt" + "shift" + " - " (minus sign next to 0, and not in the keypad if you have)